# Python3.6 could not find module "google.protobuf" unless use "help('modules')" in advance

Tags: python, ubuntu

When I run python command in ubuntu's terminal, I can import **caffe** module, but when I write the code in .py file, and run the py file ,it will throw the error **"No module named google.protobuf"**.
But if I add a command **"help('modules')"** before import caffe, then I could run the py file without any error.
And why does this command could work to solve the problem.

Comment: Are you using some kind of virtualenv?

Comment: No，I just compile and install python3.6 in the system without virtualenv